# Go headers when fetching URLs

Tags: api, go, http-headers

When I write a programme in Python and post a request using `urllib`, my header is sent to the server as `Python-urllib/3.4`

What HTTP headers are sent to a server by default when accessing an API with a Go programme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you for example just do a `http.Get` then just

```
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```